# passportjs using logged in session data in callback

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js

I have the following code for the dropbox authentication using passport js

```
passport.use(new DropboxOAuth2Strategy({
        apiVersion: '2',
        clientID: "key",
        clientSecret: "secret",
        callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/callback"
    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        // User already logged in and,
        // need to access that session data here
        console.log(profile);
        return done(null, profile);
    }
));
```

So as you can see above, the user allowes permission to my app and it works and i receive the token, tokensecret and the profile. Now the problem is i need to return a user object, which i can but i dont know how to get access to the already established session data other than through req.session.

i just want to update the user session which is already logged in, add the token, tokensecret values and return it in the "done" function.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the `req` object you can pass the `passReqToCallback` option to the `DropboxOAuth2Strategy`.

Example:

```
passport.use(new DropboxOAuth2Strategy({
        apiVersion: '2',
        clientID: "key",
        clientSecret: "secret",
        callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/callback",
        passReqToCallback: true // ask for the request object
    },
    // first argument will be the request
    function(req, token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        // User already logged in and,
        // need to access that session data here
        console.log(req.session)
        console.log(profile);
        return done(null, profile);
    }
));
```

But maybe, would be better, save in the database and retrieve the user data like this:

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ providerId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
```